# html2pdf: not show text of select option if value of this option is 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html2pdf

HTML (I have some selects with id and in option of each select can be some values = 0)
Example:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    function PDF1(){
        
            var element = document.getElementById('content');
            
            var opt = {
                
                margin: 0.5,                
                filename:     'myfile.pdf',
                
                image:        { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
                html2canvas:  { 
                    scale: 2,
                    
                },
                jsPDF:        { unit: 'in', format: 'A4', orientation: 'portrait' }
            };
            
            // Old monolithic-style usage:
            html2pdf(element, opt);
        } 

          
          $('#genpdf').click(function () {
              PDF1();
          })

});
```

```html
<select id="select4" name="select4" class="text col12" >

<option value="0">&nbsp;</option>

<option value="5">Yes</option>

<option value="0">No</option>

</select>

<div class="columns bigfotmbottom">
        <div id="printpdf" class="col12 whiteblock">
                <a href="#" class="button button-yellowbb" id="genpdf">Generate pdf</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

After clicking to the button pdf is generate. It is good. But if I select in form options with 0 values, there is no texts of its select options in selects in pdf.

I also try change html2pdf.min.js tu this file, but it not resolve the problem
https://github.com/dheerajgupta217/pdf2html/blob/main/html2pdf-tweaked-2021.min.js

Comment: Does a placeholder on your select solve your issue ?

Comment: You mean selected attribute for option? I try it - not work. Or maybe something else?
Please, write more, what you exactly mean?

Answer (score 0):

Error was because selects has options with same values.